# Symfony2 form: Money Currency Symbol and Displaying in Twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I've got a form in Symfony that uses the money field type with the currency set to GBP.

When I pass the form over to twig the form is rendered using:

```
{{ form_row(form.price) }}
```

This renders the following html:

```
£<input id="app_product_price" name="app_product[price]" required="required" class="form-control" value="9.95" type="text">
```

My aim is to try and get the currency symbol so I can use the bootstrap money field:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Transfer cash</button>
</form>
```

Obviously, there are some styling that I need to do. However, I've tried to get the currency symbol using the below but there doesn't seem to be any documentation that I can see to do this.

```
{{ form_label(form.price) }}

{{ form_widget(form.price) }}
```

Neither of these seem to work to get the currency and I have also had a look into using `{{ form_widget(form.price.vars.currency) }}` which just shows errors.

Are there any known methods of extracting the currency symbol from the form field? Or will I need to go down the route of Twig Form Theming?

Comment: Have you tried the bootstrap theme? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig

Comment: @Koalabaerchen I hadn't for this one. However, it works. Legend.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an actual answer to your question. But why bother? :)

Comment: @Koalabaerchen I'm sure there is another way, however, simple is better. No point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Add your code from the formbuilder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO there is no specific method to get the currency’s symbol ([check the Form Variables Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#twig-reference-form-variables)). The default value for the currency is :  type: string default: EUR (which correspond to the [ISO 4217 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)).

So you can simply set the currency to empty, and no symbol will be rendering:

```
$builder
->add('price', MoneyType::class, array('currency'=>''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the currency symbol with this twig regular expresion:

```
{{ form.price.vars.money_pattern | replace({ '{{ widget }}':''}) | raw }}
```